# How to solve or prove some plane geometry problems by Mathematica?

Tags: geometry

There are some plane geometry problems as my homework. I tried to solve one of them by Sketchpad which involved concurrent lines. I wonder if there is some way made through Mathematica?
For example, here is a easy problem.
[image]

And E, F are the incentre of triangle ABD and ACD, try to proof that JK, MN, GD are concurrent lines.

Comment: Express the last line extensively in math equations, as well as what the sketch is representing, add assumptions and `Reduce` or something.  I'm not sure what do you expect, MMA won't tell you *how* to solve it. It can solve it if you know how but have troubles with e.g. algebraic manipulations. Though in simple geometry the neatest solutions  usually contain no calculations. So what is the case, do you know how to solve it but struggle with implementation? If not I'm afraid this question may be too broad as there are certainly many nice ways to prove it.

Comment: Which does not mean it will be closed or you won't get any answer, community here is very forgiving.

Comment: As Kuba says, you're going to need to figure out how to translate the business in Cartesian coordinates, and work from there. `Insphere[]` is a function you can use to find the incenter of your triangles.